# How can I build a custom Subscribe button for dailymotion channel

Tags: dailymotion-api

The default layout of the badge (http://www.dailymotion.com/fr/extras/badge) is not OK for me.
I want to use my own style a design how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

depending on how much different you want it to be, you can either:

- tweak the code of the badge: adding a frameborder, changing font or color for example in those properties:

  `frameborder="0"`

  `width="300px" height="360px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"`
- re-code it yourself from scratch using the API to retrieve videos from a user's account (http://developer.dailymotion.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible to code a subscription button with the API ?

Comment: let be more specifique I didn't find in the API any way to make an API call to do a subscription to a channel. Can you help me on that ?